# Anybody knows any third party tool to synchronize lists schema between two SharePoint portals?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, list, synchronize

I am working on SharePoint development field, and I am suffering from updating the production servers with the latest changes on the development server.
Anybody knows any third party tool that synchronizes the changes between two SharePoint portals.
I am using WSS 3.0

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question but is more a bit of good practice advice that you might want to take into consideration. It doesn't sound good that your making such a quantity of changes that you need the upgrading on the production server to be automatic. Ideally you'd want a test server that matches your production server as close as possible. Possibly even to the extent of cloning the content databases for use with the test server. Upgrading the production server with such fine grained changes isn't a good idea. If a small on the fly change isn't tested properly then you can screw over the production server quite easily. To manage the risk of breaking the server the best advice I can give is develop a set of features for a milestone or release. Test it thoroughly both on your development machine and then on the test server. When you are 100% confident in it then you'd want to have a managed procedure of updating the live machine.

Back to your original question, I don't know the answer because doing so wouldn't be good practice.